# Modelling with out covering your neck, hair, or even chest

Tags: halal-haram

Is it halal and will the money gotten from this considered halal

Comment: I guess you meant the opposite!

Answer (score 0):

If your work environment contains only women, and you are sure that nothing of your picture is going to publish to public without control to strict it only to women.

unless the work is forbidden, because it's considered as helping for sin

God said in surah[5, 2]:

> ... And cooperate with one another in virtuous conduct and conscience, and do not cooperate with one another in sin and hostility. And fear God. God is severe in punishment.[Al-Maidaah, 2].

God knows.